# Define striped color in react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I have a 'react-data-table-component' and I want to basically make a dark theme. I have managed to change the background color but I also want my striped background color to be dark as well.

Here is the code:

```
createTheme('solarized', {
  text: {
    primary: 'white',
  },
  background: {
    default: '#131313',
  },
})
```

The rows go dark(#131313), white, dark, white. I don't know and can't find the striped style color.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [documentation for react-data-table-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component#defining-your-own-theme-using-createtheme). It refers you to the `themes.js` file, where you can [define the striped colour on line 37](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/master/src/DataTable/themes.js#L37).

Solution:

```
createTheme('solarized', {
  text: {
    primary: 'white',
  },
  background: {
    default: '#131313',
  },
  striped: {
    default: // ENTER YOU NEW COLOR HERE
  },
})
```