# I want to change the background for striped in react-data-table-component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

here the changes herder row BG color work for me but how we can change the BG color of the striped row.

```
import React from 'react';
    import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
    
    const tableCustomStyles = {
        headRow: {
          style: {
            color:'#223336',
            backgroundColor: '#e7eef0'
          },
        },
        striped: {
            default: 'red'
        },
      }
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h3>DataTable in React - <a href="https://www.cluemediator.com" target="_blank">Clue Mediator</a></h3>
          <DataTable
            title="Employees"
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            pagination
            highlightOnHover
            striped
            customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

here I used the react-data-table-component and want to change the customized BG color of the striped row.
how can we do that?

[image]

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258803/define-striped-color-in-react-data-table-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the documentation for using custom styles found [here](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-custom-styles--page) and the available fields [here](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/master/src/DataTable/styles.ts), it appears you need to nest the striped styles inside of a row object in the style config.

Edit for comment:

To change the order of striped and non-striped rows, you could just swap the colors of the regular rows and striped rows (i.e. set the regular row to have the striped attributes and vise-versa).

Your `tableCustomStyles` should look like this (for even row stripes):

```js
const tableCustomStyles = {
  headRow: {
    style: {
      color:'#223336',
      backgroundColor: '#e7eef0'
    },
  },
  rows: {
    style: {
      color: "STRIPEDCOLOR",
      backgroundColor: "STRIPEDCOLOR"
    },
    stripedStyle: {
      color: "NORMALCOLOR",
      backgroundColor: "NORMALCOLOR"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The above solution works for me and how we can change the Bg color order in striped @H. Ross

Comment: @AnjaliPatel I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  Do you wish to have the stripes on even rows rather than odd (or vise-versa)?

Comment: yes, I want stripes on even row @H. Ross

Comment: @AnjaliPatel Answer updated to fit your comment.

Comment: @AnjaliPatel If this has satisfied your question, feel free to accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The solution by H. Ross did not work for me. Another way to make striped rows there is to use CSS selector:

```
customStyles={{
  rows: {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      '&:nth-child(2n)': {
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
      },
    },
  },
}}
```